# How to identify the caller of a Stored Procedure from within the Sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, diagnostics

I have a deprecated stored procedure which should no longer be called from code, but there is some system which is still calling it.  This is a production server so I have very limited indirect access to it for performing diagnostics.

Is there any way to determine the machine which is calling a particular stored procedure from within the sproc?  Something such as @@CallingMachineIP or @@CallingMachineName

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select hostname from master..sysprocesses where spid=@@SPID
```

or

```
select host_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id=@@SPID
```

Comment: +1 - And if you have multiple different applications calling the procedure (Query Analyzer, Crystal Reports, etc.) you can select `program_name` as well to narrow it down

Answer (score 6):

`@@SPID` should give you the current process ID.

Then,

`select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses where
spid = @@SPID`

You can get what you need from one of those columns.