# SQL Server Query : Host name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the exact Query Text and the exact time & date the Query was executed,
how can I find the Host Name that executed this query?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: When you say Host Name, are you thinking Web Server?

Comment: Do you want `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`?

Comment: I guess that OP needs host name of the machine from which the query was executed.

Comment: you can use Sql profiler too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any table with historical information about the host that executed a query - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1334479-146-1.aspx

Comment: the query that write before gives most likely accurate results

Comment: The key point is that `sys.dm_exec_requests` returns information about requests that are **executing** and `master.dbo.sysprocesses` contains information about processes that are **running** now.

Comment: can the sql server admin know these information or have them?

Comment: I don't think they do unless you have got a profiler running at that time.

Answer (score 9):

Do you need [`@@SERVERNAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187944.aspx)

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

will return the server name where the query was executed.

---

[`HOST_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx) will return the workstation name

```
SELECT HOST_NAME()
```

Comment: this we know for sure, I'm asking about the host name or the computer name that executed this query

Answer (score 1):

You can check with HostName() as

```
SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName, SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/26/sql-server-find-hostname-and-current-logged-in-user-name/

or

```
 SELECT @IP_Address = client_net_address
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;
```

[How to get the client IP address from SQL Server 2008 itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941074/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-from-sql-server-2008-itself)

[How to identify the caller of a Stored Procedure from within the Sproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687052/how-to-identify-the-caller-of-a-stored-procedure-from-within-the-sproc)

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as you'll get, I believe:

`select host_name()`

As is mentioned in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): "The client application provides the workstation name and can provide inaccurate data. Do not rely upon HOST_NAME as a security feature."

Comment: this will give me my host name, please read the question again

Comment: I'm not asking about my host name, please read the question again

Comment: @ShahimKhlaifat Are you executing the query on the server itself? If you're going through a web app, the host_name() will return the web server.

Comment: Starting in SQL Server 2016 [Host_Name()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/host-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will return the name of the workstation.  Prior to that I think it returned something less useful.