# Where to find database_host for creating JDBC url in Azure Databricks

Tags: jdbc, azure-databricks

I'm using this tutorial https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/sql-server.html trying to connect to sql server with Azure Databricks using JDBC :

```
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

database_host = "<database-host-url>"
database_port = "1433" # update if you use a non-default port
database_name = "<database-name>"
table = "<table-name>"
user = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{database_host}:{database_port}/{database_name}"
```

Can anyone tell me where I can find the database-host-url?

Comment: Below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013577/sql-server-query-host-name might help ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Azure SQL database** -> **Connection string** ,then you can find JDBC URL.

[image]

> **Sample Code:**

```
Server_name = "<server_name>.database.windows.net"
Database = "dbase"
Port = "1433"
user_name = "<Your_User_name>"
Password = "<password>"
jdbc_Url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(Server_name, Port,Database)
conProp = {
  "user" : user_name,
  "password" : Password,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

df=spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_Url,table="<table_name>",properties=conProp)

display(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]